# eingeben or eingegeben? (passive)

Tags: passive

I have seen an example statement posted on a site.

> Wenn dreimal nacheinander die PIN falsch *eingeben* wurde, wird Ihr Zugang zum Online-Banking automatisch gesperrt.

But I think it should be

> Wenn dreimal nacheinander die PIN falsch *ein**ge**geben* wurde, wird Ihr Zugang zum Online-Banking automatisch gesperrt.

I thought because the subject is "die PIN", we should use *eingegeben* (p.p.) here. Am I not right?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're right, it should be [eingegeben](http://canoonet.eu/inflection/eingeben:V:haben).

Comment: thank you! I'm relieved my understanding is correct.:)

Comment: @ChanKim Eingeben is the infinitive form, whereas eingegeben is the perfect form